# How to find a module name and package name in Java

Tags: java

Currently i am running into this issue

```
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by my-example-class to field 
sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationInvocationHandler.memberValues
```

What I understand is that I need to add `--add-opens module/package=target-module(,target-module)*`

Knowing the full path to the field name, **where can I search** for the package name / module name so that I can pass to the `-add-opens` flag?

Right now I can only guess `--add-opens something/sun.reflect.annotation=ALL-UNNAMED`

Answer (score 2):

To get a Module by a Class, you can use the `getModule()`

```
Module module = YourClass.getModule();
```

To get the name ->

```
String moduleName = module.getName();
```

Use `this.getClass().getCanonicalName()` to get the full class name.

**Resources:**

[Way to use **getModule**](https://www.tabnine.com/code/java/methods/java.lang.Class/getModule#5ce6d506e594670004f94a90)

[Oracle documentation about **getModule**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getModule--)

[**getCanonicalName()** Method](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/class_getcanonicalname.htm)

[How to use **getCanonicalName** method](https://www.tabnine.com/code/java/methods/java.lang.Class/getCanonicalName)